# Javascript query string in single quots

Tags: javascript, string

I have some trouble with string, I always get error
**zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"**

I want the result this query is JSON formated, use this reference

https://sikandar89dubey.wordpress.com/2015/12/23/how-to-dump-data-from-redshift-to-json/

i run in dbeaver the query is work

this my code in dbeaver

```
UNLOAD ('SELECT \'{ \' || 
                case when "id" is null then \'\' else \'"id": "\' || "id" END ||
                case when "topid" is null then \'\' else \'", "topid": \' || "topid" END ||
                case when "parentid" is null then \'\' else \', "parentid": \' || "parentid" END ||
                case when "category" is null then \'\' else \', "category": "\' || "category" END ||
                case when "createdon" is null then \'\' else \'", "createdon": "\' || "createdon" END ||
                case when "updatedon" is null then \'\' else \'", "updatedon": "\' || "updatedon" END ||
       \'" }\' FROM table')
```

but when I try in javascript its error
this my query in javascript

```
`UNLOAD ('SELECT \"{ \" || 
                    case when \"id\" is null then \'\' else \"\"id\": \"\" || \"id\" END ||
                    case when \"topid\" is null then \'\' else \"\", \"topid\": \" || \"topid\" END ||
                    case when \"parentid\" is null then \'\' else \", \"parentid\": \" || \"parentid\" END ||
                    case when \"category\" is null then \'\' else \", \"category\": \"\" || \"category\" END ||
                    case when \"createdon\" is null then \'\' else \"\", \"createdon\": \"\" || \"createdon\" END ||
                    case when \"updatedon\" is null then \'\' else \"\", \"updatedon\": \"\" || \"updatedon\" END ||
                    \"\" }\" FROM table')`
```

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: why are you changing `'` to `"` since `'` works - just use the top string inside ` without change

Comment: @DipenShah so I want to run the code that is run on the dbeaver in javascript, to be precise inside a string

Comment: @JaromandaX because if it is not changed, it will give the same error, I just tried it

Comment: how can it be the same error if you changed `"` to `'`?

Comment: @JaromandaX error: syntax error at or near "{", if i not change

Comment: looks like you have four places where you have a `"` without a corresponding closing `"` ... i.e. values for `id`, `category`, `createdon` and `updatedon` - but then, you say the top code is valid, so, ...

Comment: maybe - https://pastebin.com/MJ3AKxuM

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah, its because value of topid, parentid is not string

Comment: the `then \'\'` need a comma?